# How to design the interface method for the following case?

Tags: c#, design, interfaces, generics

I am making an SNMP agent. In order to pass information to this SNMP agent, I need to periodically extract data from two different sources (and there may be more sources in future.) I am trying to design the interface for these periodic data extractors.

However, both of these extractors return different sets of information. Also, in the case of one extractor, we additionally need to pass in some state in order to get the information, while the other extractor does not need any state passed in as an argument.

So the input argument and the return type are dependent on the specific extractor. Now in order to have a common interface for these data extractors, I will need generics for both the input parameter and return type.

```
public interface DataExtractor {
  R GetData<T,R>(T state = null) where T : DataExtractInitParam;
}
```

where `DataExtractInitParam` is a marker abstract class with no fields and will inherit to create initial state parameter types. Also, it can have similar hierarchy for the return type, but all of this makes me think that the interface definition has become needlessly complex.

Although semantically the implementations of this interface are doing same thing (i.e. they follow a contract to extract data for SNMP) it is hard to come up with a simple common interface because of the different inputs and outputs of the two extractors.

Another bad thing with this design that comes to my mind is that the caller of the interface methods will be somehow able to call the method via the interface reference but in the end we will need to `downcast` the data that will be returned. So, the caller needs to know about the specific implementation's return type which altogether defeats the purpose of using an interface for loose coupling. (This makes me feel that my design is wrong).

One possible solution that I thought of is to have `void` return type and maintain the state returned by the methods as class-level global data, but again global state variables are not a good design.

I would appreciate any help designing this interface.

Comment: Is `initialState` really passed in every time you call `DataExtractor` against an implementation that needs an initial state? Or is it only on the initial call? If the latter, then it can be an implementation detail of the constructor of each class and doesn't need to be in the interface at all.

Comment: Secondly, having downcast the data, what do you do with it? Is each return type handled completely differently, or do you effectively process each type to obtain common values? If the latter, then each implementation of the interface can take on that processing task and then return a common type.

Comment: @DavidArno no this `initialState` is passed everytime to the method, not just one time. Maybe `initialState` is not the correct word. I will rephrase it. And regarding the return types, the data from each extractor will be combined to form final information to be sent to the Snmp agent. So, basically it is like fetching data from all sources and then combining it.

Comment: And Is it like for example, one source provides some products and the other provides some more products? Or rather one source provides product names and ids and the other provides prices by ids? But I suppose the latter if you say they have different return types...

Comment: @slepic It is like one source provides one part of entire information and other source provides other part. Both these sets of information are totally different from each other.

Comment: Then I am afraid that there is no common interface for the two sources.

Comment: They are not doing the same job. Would it still work if you switched the first extractor with the other?

Comment: @slepic no, it will not work. So should I just not create any interface and just have concrete classes?

Comment: Yes. Although you can still define two separate interfaces for the two extractors. This will allow you easier mocking of the extractors in tests of the class that will combine them and also avoid need to modify that class when one of the extractors implementations need to be replaced by a new one.

Comment: Is the intent to specify a method with a fixed input and output type, or each implementation supports all input and output types?  (T,R).  I ask, because where you declare the generics has a very different meaning.

Comment: For example, why not this?

     public interface DataExtractor<T,R>
       where T : DataExtractInitParam
    {
      R GetData(T state = null);
    }

Comment: "*...need to pass in some state in order to get the information*" -- Can this be loaded by some config file, or is it determined/resolved only at runtime, to be passed on to the extractor?